# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" while running makemigrations

Tags: python, django

getting the below error while running makemigrations

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 127, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/siva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

code in my settings file to import

```
try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your settings.py DATABASES dict?
It should contain your password as a string, so including quotation marks ('').

Comment: This password works when you try to manually log in to Pg admin?

Comment: yes , even  I reset  the password to double check, still getting the error

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'sampledb',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'****',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',

    }
}

Comment: Can you try and change the engine to 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' 
I presume you validated the host, port and db name also?

Comment: Thanks for inputs  , the issue with password only , I Corrected it ,  now its working